# String Formatting Not working with Eval

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have following expression for currency formatting inside an ASP.Net Gridview. It does not show dollar format though there is no error. What is the missing point here?

```
<%# String.Format("{0:C}", Convert.ToString(Eval("Amount")) ) %>
```

**MARKUP**

```
 <asp:GridView ID="grdFinancialAmount" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Emp ID">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <%# Eval("EmpID")%>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Amount">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <%# String.Format("{0:C}", Convert.ToString(Eval("Amount")) ) %>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

**CODE BEHIND**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Financial fin1 = new Financial { EmpID = 1, Amount = 5678 };
    Financial fin2 = new Financial { EmpID = 2, Amount = -111111 };

    List<Financial> accounts = new List<Financial>();
    accounts.Add(fin1);
    accounts.Add(fin2);

    grdFinancialAmount.DataSource = accounts;
    grdFinancialAmount.DataBind();


}


public class Financial
{
    public int EmpID { get; set; }
    public int Amount { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Why not just do either...

```
<%# String.Format("{0:C}", Eval("Amount") ) %>
```

or

```
<%# ((int)Eval("Amount")).ToString("C") %>
```

Looks to me like you are trying to convert Amount to a string twice, and you can't format a string as currency.

Comment: Edited. Forgot to cast to an integer.

Comment: I assume that it is because Int32 (int) implements IFormattable and provides a ToString(string format) method which String.Format will call depending on the format template given.

Answer (score 9):

`Eval` accepts a string format, and there is no need for these hacks.

As simple as: `<%# Eval("Amount", "{0:C}") %>`

Answer (score 6):

try this, works for me. (.NET 4.5 C#, in a gridview)

```
<%#Eval("Amout", "{0:C}").ToString()%>
```

Comment: Note: `.ToString()` will cause problems if the field is `NULL`.

Answer (score 3):

try this :

```
<%# String.Format("{0:C}", int.Parse(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Amount").ToString()))  %>
```

Comment: @Lijo I think I forgot the .DataItem. please try now ( Ive edited)